# combine similar consecutive observations into one observation in R

Tags: r, statistics, usage-statistics

I have a data set like this

```
date ID key value
05   1   3   2
05   1   3   5
05   1   3   1
05   1   5   2
05   1   7   3
05   1   7   3
05   1   3   4
05   2   9   8
```

I need the output to look like this

```
date ID key value
05   1   3   8
05   1   5   2
05   1   7   6
05   1   3   4
05   2   9   8
```

so as you see if **consecutive** date, ID, and key are the same , I want to know how to combine these observation and add their value. **I need this to happen only if the events where consecutive.**
is it possible to do it r?
if yes, can anyone please tell me how to do it?
thanks

Comment: @user20650 : OP specifically says he only wants to combine consecutive observations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rle` to look for consecutive sequences

```
# your data
df <- read.table(text="date ID key value
 05   1   3   2
 05   1   3   5
 05   1   3   1
 05   1   5   2
 05   1   7   3
 05   1   7   3
 05   1   3   4
 05   2   9   8", header=T)

# get consecutive values - add a grouping variables
r <- with(df, rle(paste(date, ID, key)))
df$grps <- rep(seq(r$lengths), r$lengths)

# aggregate values
a <- aggregate(value ~ date + ID + key + grps, data = df , sum)

# remove the grouping variable
a$grps <- NULL
```